# Multiple btrfs volumes with different RAID levels on the same devices

Tags: btrfs

I have two disks - one xGB and one (2x)GB. I would like to have one mountpoint from these disks under raid0 and one under raid1, spread over the total available space. Is that possible with btrfs without creating two fixed-size primary partitions on each disk?

What I would like is this layout:

```
disk1 |< -- /home (raid1) -- >< -- /backups (raid0) -- >|
disk2 |< -- /home (raid1) -- >< -- /backups (raid0) ----------------------- >|
```

Each mount point should expand as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not available in btrfs, as of October 2015 at least.

This feature, known as per-subvolume raid levels, is commonly requested.

The [official FAQ](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Why_is_free_space_so_complicated.3F) says this is planned for the future, but I haven't seen anything predicting when.